# Regex: match a single word in a set inside negative lookbehind

Tags: regex

I want to build a regex that will catch inside a text all strings (start and finish with "/') that are not inside square brackets and are not inside the patterns name()/city()/number()

This is what I got for now:

```
/(?<![name|city|number]\(|\[)(["'])[^\)|^\]]+?(?<!\\)\1/g
```

it works OK but not the best.
For example: it doens't catch the strings inside a() and n(), although I want the regex to catch it.

[image]

[link to the regex](https://regex101.com/r/0L8gWn/1)

The problem is here:

```
[name|city|number]
```

It use it as 'or' of single characters and not as 'or' of words like I want it to be.

How can I fix my regex to behave like I want without ruin the rest of it?

Comment: I meant start with ' or ". I got my answer thanks

Comment: `[name|city|number]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), same like `[abceimnrtuy|]`. It does not do what you expect it to do. Also please specifiy what tool/lang you're using. You'd need to alternate the words within a [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) inside the lookbheind but this would make it variable-width which in PCRE is not supported. An idea to get around it: [`(?<!(?:name|city|(?<=nu)mber)\(|\[)`...](https://regex101.com/r/x8EJOM/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to  get out of the what you don't want to have by matching it, and use a capture group to capture what you want.

Note as mentioned that `[name|city|number]` is a character class and not a grouping.

```
\b(?:name|city|number)\([^()]*\)|\[[^\][]*]|("[^"]*"|'[^']*')(?<!\\.)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:name|city|number)` Match any of the words in the alternation
- `\([^()]*\)` Match from `(...)`
- `|` Or
- `|\[[^\][]*]` Match from `[...]`
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `"[^"]*"|'[^']*'` Match either from `"..."` or `'...'`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?<!\\.)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `\` before the previous char

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vyrylg/1)

As you have selected PCRE2 in your regex link, there is also an option using SKIP FAIL and get a match only:

```
(?:\b(?:name|city|number)\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*])(*SKIP)(*F)|\K(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')(?<!\\.)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xv3z02/1)

Comment: thanks, I selected by mistake PCRE2 (I saw the second regex it's looks great but I need it to work in JavaScript.) About the first demo: it's also catch name("hi"), name('hi') but I need it to ignore strings inside name|city|number. Do you know how can I fix the first regex in order to work?

Answer (score 1):

Making each of those into it's own negative lookbehind seems to do the trick

`(?<!name\(|\[)(?<!city\(|\[)(?<!number\(|\[)(["'])[^\)|^\]]+?(?<!\\)\1`

https://regex101.com/r/E91W5a/1

Comment: Hi @randommm, this really nice regex but I found a problem for example: j("h)i")  the regex doesn't recognize the string "h)i" because there is the char )  inside the string. Do you have an idea how to fix it? [link](https://regex101.com/r/eQ8C4r/1)